# java why this result is printed

Tags: java

I have two classes below:

```
public class Echo {
    int ilosc = 0;
    void witaj() {
        System.out.println("sieeeemasz... ");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class EchoTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Echo e1 = new Echo();
        Echo e2 = new Echo();
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 4) {
            e1.witaj();
            e1.ilosc = e1.ilosc + 1; 
            if (x == 3) {
                e2.ilosc = e2.ilosc + 1; 
            }
            if (x > 0) {
                e2.ilosc = e2.ilosc + e1.ilosc; 
            }
            x = x + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(e2.ilosc);
    }
}
```

The console print the results which are valid for this exercise :

```
sieeeemasz... 
sieeeemasz... 
sieeeemasz... 
sieeeemasz... 
10
```

My question is about the last line - why 10? if anyone can tell me how does it work?

Comment: Use pen and paper to keep track of `ilosc` values of the two `Echo` objects.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: 1. Indent yor code properly, it's unreadable. 2. Execute every instruction on paper and write the value of each variable after each instruction, and you'll know. Or use your debugger to step through the code and inspect the values of the variables after each instruction.

Comment: You'd be amazed how much easier reading code is when it's properly indented.

Answer (score 1):

With pen and paper you can keep track of the values of the members of the objects. This is a better approach before using a debugger, since your problem is pretty simple. When you have lots of variables to keep track of and their values changes lots of times and in subtle ways it is better to use a debugger.

[image]

Comment: That is a solid graphic...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a Debugger to go over the program Step-by-Step. Personally I've thrown your code into BlueJ, set a breakpoint and have gotten all the information why it is that way.

Here's fully what happens:

1. `e1.ilosc` is set to 1 (0 + 1) in Line 8
2. At the next run through the Loop, `e1.ilosc` is increased by 1 again
3. As x=1 now the if-Statement in Line 13 triggers, adding `e1.ilosc` to `e2.ilosc` (2+0), setting `e2.ilosc` to 2.
4. x is increased by 1, `e1.ilosc` is increased by 1, making it 3.
5. The if in Line 13 triggers again, adding `e1.ilosc` to `e2.ilosc` (3+2). `e2.ilosc` is 5 now.
6. `e1.ilosc` gets increased to 4, x gets increased to 3, the if at Line 10 triggers, `e2.ilosc` gets increased by 1, making it 6.
7. The if in Line 13 still fires and adds `e1.ilosc`(4) to `e2.ilosc`(6) again. 4+6=10 so `e2.ilosc` is 10 now.

x gets increased to 4, the loop stops executing and the program prints 10.